# Accessing an app database through ADB multiple times without closing the connection?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, adb

I am using ADB to access an app database like this:

```
public static int runCommandInt(String arg1) {
    try {
            ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder(adbLocation, "shell", "sqlite3",
                "/data/data/com.package/databases/Database.db", arg1);
            Process p = proc.start();
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            String s = null;
            int i = 0;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                i = Integer.parseInt(s);
                p.destroyForcibly();
                return i;
            }
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The problem with this, however, is that every time I try to run a command, it opens and closes adb (and therefore the database connection as well - which is extremely inefficient), is there a way to get the same adb window and execute more commands there?

It **has** to go through adb unfortunately. Pulling the database every second and checking locally leaves too much room for error.

Comment: do you have any other complaints about this way of achieving your goal other than you think it's inefficient? If all you need is to query a few values every second - I would not change a thing. If you have other issues - let us hear about those.

Answer (score 0):

create process that starts command prompt that redirects standard input and standard error

then write commands to standard input like the following

p.standardinput.writeline("adb command goes here");
when command completes or using asyncronous reading of standard error or output to get your returned information

Answer (score -1):

Yes, good question! Check out this code for a ConnectionManager! It uses what is called a Singleton pattern, where the only constructor for a `ConstructionManager` object is `private`. You use a `getInstance` method in order to acquire the instance of the database connection. If there is already an instance of the connection, it just returns the `Connection` that already exists. Otherwise, it goes ahead and constructs a new one. That way, you only have to connect the first time.

```
public class ConnectionManager {
    private static ConnectionManager instance = null;

    private final String USERNAME = "corbin";
    private final String PASSWORD = "letmein";
    private final String CONNECTION = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\Users\\Corbin\\Java Proj\\TaskTracker\\Kurafuto\\db";

    private Connection conn = null;

    private ConnectionManager() {
    }

    public static ConnectionManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ConnectionManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private boolean openConnection() {
        try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connection Opened!");
        return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return false;
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (conn == null) {
        if (openConnection()) {
            return conn;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public void close() {
       System.out.println("Closing connection...");
        try {
        conn.close();
        conn = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Get the `Connection` with `ConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();`

Comment: This does not answer my question, because it doesn't go through ADB.